# rails foreign key setup with AR and postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, database-schema

I just realized I have some issues when deleting parent models.

I have this setup:

user.rb

```
has_many :conversations, foreign_key: "sender_id", dependent: :destroy
```

conversation.rb

```
belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "sender_id"
belongs_to :recipient, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "recipient_id"
```

schema (postgres DB)

```
add_foreign_key "conversations", "users", column: "recipient_id"
add_foreign_key "conversations", "users", column: "sender_id"
```

As you can guess if `user.destroy` is called and there is a conversation where the user is the recipient then it will raise `PG::ForeignKeyViolation ERROR: update or delete on table conversations violates foreign key constraint...`

To deal with this problem I'm planning to do the following:

user.rb

```
#this will solve the rails side of the problem
has_many :received_conversations, class_name: "Conversation", foreign_key: "recipient_id", dependent: :destroy
```

schema (DB):

```
#this will solve the DB side of the problem
add_foreign_key "conversations", "users", column: "recipient_id", on_delete: :cascade
add_foreign_key "conversations", "users", column: "sender_id", on_delete: :cascade
```

Is this the right way to solve this issue?

Comment: Check out this post on referential integrity and foreign key constraints for rails.  It looks like you're spot on thus far.

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/referential-integrity-with-foreign-keys

Comment: Thanks bkunzi01! I have one more question after reading the article. Would you heep `dependent: :destroy` on the rails side as well? The article says it could be deleted, but I would rather keep it.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to mention foreign_key relation in:

```
has_many :conversations, foreign_key: "sender_id", dependent: :destroy
```

as you already maintain this relation in belongs_to. If you remove the above foreign key relation, dependent: :destroy will destroy your corresponding conversation records as well of the deleted user record let it be the recepient or sender

Comment: SnehaT, I have one more model (notifications) that has the same setup like conversations, and there I call `user.notifications` since I wanna list them. So in that case does my solution work? And what about db side?

Comment: Yeah it will work for notifications model as well. If you delete any user, it will delete the corresponding notifications.